# onChange vs onKeyPress for input in React

Tags: comparative-review, form, event-handling, react.js, jsx

I have an input form, and when you press enter I want it to call a function. I was wondering what "the right" way of doing this is.

Right now I have an input looking like this:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Enter key words" 
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleChange} 
    onKeyPress={this.handleEnter}
/>
```

And two functions that look like this

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleEnter(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value},function(){
            this.props.theFunction(this.state.value);
        });
    }
}
```

Another solution was to point both onChange and onKeyPress to the same function and write it like

```
handleChangeAndEnter(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value},function(){
            this.props.theFunction(this.state.value);
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
}
```

If I remove the onChange-binding the input-field stops updating itself on input (not entirely sure why this is) and if I remove the onKeyPress-binding the event-object no longer has a key-property.

My current solution works, but it still feels like a hack.

Answer (score 4):

Don't complicate your code; the first solution is just fine but needs some tweaking:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleEnter(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        this.props.theFunction(this.state.value);
    }
}
```

Or, you can use what they call a guard clause and make it short and readable:

```
handleEnter(event) {
    if (event.key !== 'Enter') return; 
    this.props.theFunction(this.state.value);
}
```

And if you're using react hooks:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
}

const handleEnter = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        if (value !== "") {
            console.log("Hello", name);
        } 
        else {
            alert("can't pass empty string");
        }
        setInputValue("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to React, so bear with me. ;)

If you use the state in the enter handler exclusively, you don’t need the state at all.

```
handleChangeAndEnter(event) {
  if (event.key !== 'Enter') { return; }
  this.props.theFunction(event.target.value);
}
```

If you use it for other things, I would recommend something like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}

handleEnter(event) {
  if (event.key !== 'Enter') { return; }
  this.props.theFunction(this.state.value);
}
```

There is no need to change the state in `handleEnter`, because the state already reflects the current value.